# yii how to change uploaded file name

Tags: php, yii, upload

I want to upload a image and change the original name then save it.

Model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
        );
    }
```

Controller:

```
$model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
```

If i save it without any other actions it will work.
But how could i change the name of image ? I try something like below:

```
$model->image->name = "xxx";  //CUploadedFile.name readonly

if($model->save())
    $model->images->saveAs(some_path_else.newname);  //the files's new name is different from database


 $model->image = "abc.jpg";  //wont save it
```

Is the image attribute must be an instance of CUploadedFile?
Anyone help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
I figured it out.
CUploadedFile.name is read only , so i can't change it.
The Model need a new public attribute :

```
public $file;    
public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                array('file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
                array('iamge', 'length'=>'255'),
            );
        }
```

Then in the controller:

```
$model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
$model->file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../public/images/user/' . $model->image);
$model->image = $model->file->name;
```

It's works fine.(it's not real code)
[see here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/)

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
if (!empty($uploadedFile)) {
    //new name will go here
    $model->image = strtotime($this->getCurrentDateTime()) . '-' .$uploadedFile;
}
//this will save the image with new name
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../public/images/user/' . $model->image);
```

Comment: if $model->image is  string , I will get an error " Image cannot be blank".

Comment: $model->images & $model->image are they two different property in Model ?

Comment: sorry , my mistake. there's no $model->images, only $model->image

Comment: can you post complete code of your action (of your controller) in question